# add Delete linklabel column whenever new record will be added

Tags: c#, winforms

In my windows form application I want to add `Delete` linklabel against each data row and I am doing below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace search
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Documents and Settings\\Musewerx\\My Documents\\Contacts.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True");
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            bindDatagridview();
        }
        public void bindDatagridview()
        {
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("Select * from contactsinfo", connection);
            da.Fill(ds);

            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

            clear();
            DataGridViewLinkColumn dgvLink = new DataGridViewLinkColumn();
            dgvLink.UseColumnTextForLinkValue = true;
            dgvLink.LinkBehavior = LinkBehavior.SystemDefault;
            dgvLink.HeaderText = "";
            dgvLink.Name = "lnk_delete";
            dgvLink.LinkColor = Color.Blue;
            dgvLink.TrackVisitedState = true;
            dgvLink.Text = "Delete";
            dgvLink.UseColumnTextForLinkValue = true;

            bool check = dataGridView1.Columns.Contains("dgvLink");
            if(check == false)
            {
                dataGridView1.Columns.Add(dgvLink);
            }
        }

        public void clear()
        {
            textBox1.Text = string.Empty;
            textBox2.Text = string.Empty;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (textBox1.Text == string.Empty)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Enter Contact Name");
            }
            else if(textBox2.Text == string.Empty)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Enter Contact Number");
            }
            else
            {
            da.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand("Insert into contactsinfo(ContactName,ContactNumber) Values('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "')", connection);
            connection.Open();
            da.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            bindDatagridview();
            clear();
            connection.Close();
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 f2 = new Form2();
            f2.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

but the problem is that each time when I enter new record new column of `Delete` linklabel will be added, And I want that only one time a `Delete` linklabel column will be added.

kindly suggest me, waiting for your reply.
Thanks.

Comment: just put an if condition to check the column already exists. If not exists then add. Otherwise dont add.

Comment: @ray: on your suggestion, I have edit my post, but still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like This

change "dgvLink"  to "lnk_delete". "lnk_delete" is column name.

```
 DataGridViewLinkColumn dgvLink = new DataGridViewLinkColumn();
 dgvLink.UseColumnTextForLinkValue = true;
 dgvLink.LinkBehavior = LinkBehavior.SystemDefault;
 dgvLink.HeaderText = "";
 dgvLink.Name = "lnk_delete";
 dgvLink.LinkColor = Color.Blue;
 dgvLink.TrackVisitedState = true;
 dgvLink.Text = "Delete";
 dgvLink.UseColumnTextForLinkValue = true;

  bool check = dataGridView1.Columns.Contains("lnk_delete");
  if (check == false)
  {
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(dgvLink);
  }
```